# Stop Mic Listening please?

Tags: microphone

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

I typed the above command to listen to my mic. Now I am always listening, how do i stop!?

Now i just typed the following and now i have no sound at all. please help me!

```
 pactl exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With loading the pulseaudio loopback module you had made your microphone loop back to the audio output.

To reverse this just unload this module again:

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

To unload all modules we had added in addition to those defined in our `default.pa` we can also reset and restart the pulseaudio server with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

This will then load only modules from the `default.pa`.